# How do install packages from a local python package index?

Tags: python, pip, pypi

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0503 and https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_wheel/#cmdoption-i allude to being able to install python packages from a local directory, but it's not quite explicitly clear what this looks like in practice.

Do I use the same index.html files in my local directories? What does the argument to the --extra-index-url look like for a local directory?

Comment: To clarify, I want to be able to install using a requirements.txt, e.g. `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Answer (score 8):

If you have a directory of distributions you want searched by pip, you may simply include the path to the directory:

```
pip install --extra-index-url=file:///path/to/wheelhouse somepackage
```

The `/path/to/wheelhouse` should to be structured like a simple repository, see [*PEP 503 – Simple Repository API*](https://peps.python.org/pep-0503/). It is not necessary to run a webserver, serving from the filesystem is okay. A local directory of releases (e.g. `.tar.gz` and `.whl` files) can be made into the correct repository structure by running [`piprepo build /path/to/wheelhouse`](https://github.com/colinhoglund/piprepo).

You could use `--index-url` instead of `--extra-index-url` if you don't want the remote PyPI searched at all.  Note it's also possible to add `--extra-index-url` and/or `--index-url` at the top of your `requirements.txt` file.

Using `pip`, you can also install a distribution directly from a local file.
For example, to install the [copyingmock](https://pypi.python.org/simple/copyingmock/) distribution:

```
$ curl https://pypi.python.org/packages/d9/26/5ae8945356634c87cdf099bd7cee57799df46798af90ae5ccb03961c6359/copyingmock-0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl > copyingmock-0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
$ pip install ./copyingmock-0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

I've shown an example with a binary distribution, but the same should work for source distributions (.tar.gz).

Answer (score 6):

Let's say you have 2 packages you want to install from locally: `abc-xyz` and `foo`, and you have your corresponding package files `abc-xzy-1.2.3.tar.gz` and `foo-1.0.0.tar.gz`.

We'll put your local pypi directory at `/my_local_pypi/simple`

Your directory structure will look like:

```
/my_local_pypi/simple
  index.html
  - abc-xyz/
     index.html     
     abc-xyz-1.2.3.tar.gz  
  - foo/
     index.html
     foo-1.0.0.tar.gz
```

The root `index.html` needs `<a href></a>` anchor entries for each package, so should look like:

```
$ cat /my_local_pypi/simple/index.html
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<a href="abc-xyz">abc-xyz></a></br>
<a href="foo">foo</a></br>
</body></html>
```

Then each `$package/index.html` needs an `<a href></a>` anchor pointing to the actual package file, so they should look like:

```
$ cat /my_local_pypi/simple/abc-xyz/index.html
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<a href="abc-xyz-1.2.3.tar.gz">abc-xyz-1.2.3.tar.gz</a></br>
</body></html>

$ cat /my_local_pypi/simple/foo/index.html
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<a href="foo-1.0.0.tar.gz">foo-1.0.0.tar.gz</a></br>
</body></html>
```

Then in your `requirements.txt`, you can do:

```
$ cat requirements.txt
--extra-index-url file:///my_local_pypi/simple/
abc-xyz==1.2.3
foo==1.0.0
```

And then you should be good to go: `pip install -r requirements.txt`

See also the [piprepo](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/piprepo) project, which does a pretty good job of generating the local directory structure needed.

Answer (score 2):

You won't have to use any `index.html` files.

Running the following should suffice:

`pip install "path/to/file.whl"`

This will install from local wheel file.

Comment: Can you use paths like that from a requirements.txt file also?